# Remove Price from New Products block on Homepage

Tags: magento-1.8, price, product-attribute

Hi I wanted to see if anyone knew how to remove(Hide) the price from Magento's main home page under the new products section block. I was able to remove the price from the list/grid thanks to some other post suggestions. Not Sure where else to look for the new products section on the home page.

I've tried commenting out under `template/catalog/product/new.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?>
```

But that didn't do anything.
CMS Page homepage layout

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" template="catalog/msrp/popup.phtml" name="product.tooltip"></block>
    <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms.wrapper">
        <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
        <action method="setProductsCount"><count>8</count></action>
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Thanks for any help.
References.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510528/magento-remove-price-phtml-from-the-category-list-of-products

Comment: Can you post the content of your homepage as it is found in cms->pages? Or alt least the part that renders the new products?

Comment: Hopefully i added the right thing... But now that you mentioned that would i be looking under the bundle/catalog_product_price. I ve tried using the tag highlights under debug but it didn't really help lead me to the specific price location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes This is the right template file to remove the price from the new product listing.

comment the code in the below template file:

```
template/catalog/product/new.phtml


<?php //echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?>
```

But just make sure to refresh Magento's cache form the admin side.

Follow the steps to refresh the cache:
Go to

```
System >> Cache Management
```

[image]

select all the cache and refresh them. now the result will be displayed

Note: if you are in development phase make all cache as disabled.